# Python import error in Jupyter Notebook Pycharm 2019 IDE

Tags: python, pycharm, jupyter-notebook, jetbrains-ide, jetbrains-hub

I recently installed PyCharm 2019 professional edition in Windows 10. I created a new Project 'Sample' and two files 'file1.py' and 'file2.ipynb'. I have installed jupyter notebook from the chosen python interpreter.

1. class Foo is defined in file1.py
2. I then import file1.py into file2.ipynb to use Foo

Here, I encounter a strange error. 2019 professional edition has local notebook server installed in it.

```
from file1 import Foo
```

I ran the above code sample in a cell both in editor inside PyCharm IDE as well as in browser, after turning on the jupyter server on localhost.

For some reason, the code sample throws out import error problem in IDE but runs smoothly in browser. I tried looking if there are any issues with project path but couldn't figure out the reason yet. Anyone encountered this before ?

Here is the screenshot of Import Error:
[image]

Comment: Can you please add the `ImportError` to your question?

Comment: Does the error message complain about `file1` or about `Foo`? That's quite important, and your redacted version of the error message leaves us in the dark.

Comment: check for case (lower or upper)

Comment: I am sorry, it complains about file1 @BoarGules

Comment: I have gone through the link you shared. @IonicSolutions There its clearly some path issue, as its working on terminal but not in IDE...Here, I am facing the problem between IDE and browser on localhost.  Also, that post refers to 2015 IDE.

Comment: I am sure the problem is not with case here, I checked it @Vishal

Comment: I tired that option before posting it here. It didn't work. I guess the problem here is with jupyter notebook on pycharm IDE. python import in other python files are working for me @IonicSolutions ... Did the link you mentioned in your last comment worked for this problem? Are you able to import it ?

Comment: file1.py is probably not in the current working directory.

Comment: @praneeth, Goya's comment could also be a potential reason.

Comment: I tried even by placing file1.py both inside and outside of current directory.  Unfortunately, still the same error. Maybe that's not the reason for this error @Goyo

Comment: can you show how your file1.py looks like?

Comment: Can you show the output of `os.getcwd()`?

Comment: Can you add path till file1.py? for example from com.util.file1 import Foo ?

Comment: I think you may be wrong about what the current directory is.

Answer (score 0):

os.getcwd() helped me understand the problem. The jupyter notebook editor is running under Main directory 'Sample'. Whereas my files are in 'Sample/Resource/file1.py', 'Sample/Resource/file2.ipynb' .

Now If I import using the following commands in file2.ipynb file, it worked:

```
import os
print(os.getcwd())
#%%
from Source import file1
print(file1.Foo())
```

Thank you very much for the help @Vishal @IonicSolutions